# MySQL: Unable to query between two dates if one date is in 2015 and other is in 2016

Tags: mysql

Been using the below query for the last year but now that we are crossing into a new year, it seems to have stopped working (at least for this week). Don't understand why...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE userID = 67 AND date BETWEEN '12/27/2015' AND '01/02/2016'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Wrong date format, I'd be surprised if you didn't have problems before now. Try `BETWEEN '2015-12-27' AND '2016-01-02'`.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `date` column?

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately, the database was created before I came into the picture and it is set as varchar. I don't think I can change it without messing up other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If date is a column of type date, you should write your dates with this format:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE userID = 67 AND date BETWEEN '2015-12-27' AND '2016-01-02'
```

if date is a varchar instead, and the format is correct, you could try with this:

```
WHERE str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2015-12-27' AND '2016-01-02'
```

but I would suggest you not to store dates as strings.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am not the creator of the database and it is set as varchar. Don't know if there would be a way around this?

Comment: @lcp2000 you can use str_to_date, it will work but performances cannot be optimal